# What should I do to create iOS Build in React Native Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

Reason: Unknown reason, raw: {"type":"Spaceship::ProgramLicenseAgreementUpdated","message":"You currently don't have access to this membership resource. To resolve this issue, agree to the latest Program License Agreement in your developer account. Please manually log into your Apple Developer account to review and accept the updated agreement.","backtrace":["/mnt/c/Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/traveling-fastlane-1.11.4-linux-x86_64/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.136.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:742:in `detect_most_common_errors_and_raise_exceptions'","/mnt/c/Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/traveling-fastlane-1.11.4-linux-x86_64/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.136.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:708:in`parse_response'","/mnt/c/Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/traveling-fastlane-1.11.4-linux-x86_64/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.136.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/portal/portal_client.rb:115:in `block in apps'","/mnt/c/Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/traveling-fastlane-1.11.4-linux-x86_64/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.136.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:317:in`block in paging'","/mnt/c/Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/traveling-fastlane-1.11.4-linux-x86_64/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.136.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:315:in `loop'","/mnt/c/Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/traveling-fastlane-1.11.4-linux-x86_64/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.136.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:315:in`paging'","/mnt/c/Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/traveling-fastlane-1.11.4-linux-x86_64/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.136.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/portal/portal_client.rb:108:in `apps'","/mnt/c/Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/traveling-fastlane-1.11.4-linux-x86_64/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.136.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/portal/app.rb:85:in`all'","/mnt/c/Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/traveling-fastlane-1.11.4-linux-x86_64/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.136.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/portal/app.rb:111:in `find'","/mnt/c/Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/traveling-fastlane-1.11.4-linux-x86_64/lib/app/ensure_app_exists.rb:21:in`ensure_app_exists'","/mnt/c/Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/traveling-fastlane-1.11.4-linux-x86_64/lib/app/ensure_app_exists.rb:42:in `block in <main>'","/mnt/c/Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/traveling-fastlane-1.11.4-linux-x86_64/lib/app/funcs.rb:4:in`with_captured_stderr'","/mnt/c/Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/traveling-fastlane-1.11.4-linux-x86_64/lib/app/ensure_app_exists.rb:38:in `'"]}

This is the error I am getting in Console. But I am unable to resolve this. If anyone has any idea, please share.

Comment: Which OS you are using? Do you have an enterprise account with apple appstore?

Comment: I am using Windows 10. Yes I have Paid Apple Account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> message":"You currently don't have access to this membership resource.
>   To resolve this issue, agree to the latest Program License Agreement
>   in your developer account. Please manually log into your Apple
>   Developer account to review and accept the updated agreement."

Try to access this URL http://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action and login with your Apple developer account. You need to agree to the licenses there.

I've seen some cases where people report that it's better to do this in Safari (sometimes the alerts don't show in other browsers)

Comment: So, is Apple need any payment for this?